# Can I still set my account picture to an image from disk in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, accounts

I can't seem to browse my hard disk for a custom image to use as my account picture anymore since installing OS X Mountain Lion.

The new popover shows that I can now only choose from the default set of pictures, pick something I've recently used, or take a new one with my Mac's iSight camera:

[image]

<sup>(I have no real inclination towards golf.)</sup>

There was always a Choose button in the panel dialog in previous versions of OS X, but now it's gone. Is there no way to browse my disk for a custom image anymore on Mountain Lion, or is there hopefully a `defaults` switch somewhere that I need to flip to enable it again?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can drag in any picture from the Finder into the Preference Pane to change the custom image. Not as convenient as using the Open Dialog though...

Comment: Strange why I hadn't thought of that — I'd just done exactly the same thing an hour ago, except with a login item. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know... I just switched from the Windows world a couple of weeks ago and there are little things like that that throw me off at times.  I'd say I strongly prefer the Open/Save dialog on Windows though (for everything). The one in Finder has a few shortcomings in comparison.

Comment: I've been using OS X for 5+ years now and I still trip over these "intuitive" interfaces pretty frequently.

Comment: [Q&A for MacOS 13 Ventura](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452118/setting-the-account-picture-from-a-jpg-or-png-on-ventura)