# Setting the account picture from a JPG or PNG on Ventura

Tags: ventura

In the past it was possible to set the account picture from a image file on the disk.
You'd drag the images from Finder to the user account picture, and voila it's done.

But this doesn't work on Ventura (13.1). Dragging the image doesn't do anything.

Is there something broken or is there a different procedure.

[screen recording](https://imgur.com/YHD9bK2.mp4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the right procedure:

> Tip: To quickly replace the current Apple ID picture with an image on your Mac, just drag the image from the Finder onto the current picture.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mtusr002/mac

However, there's only one drop zone that appears to work: the one from the ⓘ button.

[image]

Comment: Indeed I saw this guide before asking the question, but clearly the guide is unclear on the fact one need to open the info panel and drag over the picture here. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Because @grg's answer was too terse and wrong (there are are least 2 places you can drop an image, not one)

The instructions on the Apple site are arguably wrong, at least on Ventura 13.1.  ([See video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzPchZZeOWc)) as in the context of Apple's instructions this is the current picture.

[image]

There are at least 6 places where your "current picture" appears but only two of them work. You can see at 5 places where your "current picture" appears in these screenshots (1: left panel, 2: apple id, 3: users and groups list, 4: info dialog, 5: the select icon dialog)

1. Pick account

[image]

This will then bring up the dialog that lets you select an icon but the icon on the left will be filled with the image you just dropped so you can just click "Save"

2. From System Settings pick "Users and Groups" then click the ⓘ button

[image]

Then drag an image to the icon

[image]